# my sql sometimes ok, but sometimes failed

Tags: php, sql

I was writing the php to query the MySQL DB, but **the sql sentence works sometimes but failed sometimes .**when it works, it will return records, when it failed it will say: **You have an error in your SQL syntax.** I don't know how to fix it,please give me a hand.thanks.the *_id and type is integer,others are string or date type.

```
function getMyAwardRecords()
 {
global $db, $userId, $nickName;

$result0 = $db->fetchrows("SELECT user_nick,type,create_date FROM records WHERE type=0 AND user_id={$userId}");
// echo $userId;
$result = $db->fetchrows("SELECT records.user_nick, records.type, records.create_date, awards.code FROM records, awards WHERE records.award_id = awards.award_id AND records.user_id = {$userId}");
$result = array_merge($result, $result0);
// print_r($result);
if($result)
{
    echo ajaxResponse(200,$result);
}
else
  {
    echo ajaxResponse(400);
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: The actual SQL statement would be helpful.

Comment: It's probably failing sometimes with a syntax error because you are sticking arbitrary data into a query.  Use prepared/parametrized queries.  What you have now is insecure and unreliable.

Comment: Brad's advice is inspire for me.

Comment: Put `{$userId}` in single quotation mark `user_id='{$userId}'` and SQL will treat this as string. But prepared/parametrized queries are better - as Brad said.